# How to bind to a combobox using butterknife?

Tags: android, butterknife

Using [Butterknife](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/), how can I declare a method that is called when the combobox is selected or deselected? Using `@OnItemSelected` gives a `ClassCastException`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox 
                              cannot be cast to android.widget.AdapterView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

It is better to use `@OnCheckedChanged` like this:

```
    @OnCheckedChanged(R.id.myCheckBox)
    void myCheckBoxSelected(boolean checked) {
        // use checked here
    }
```

The advantage is that you immediately get the boolean flag.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

You need to use the `@OnClick` annotation:

```
    @OnClick(R.id.myCheckBox)
    void myCheckBoxSelected(CheckBox checkBox) {
        boolean checked = checkBox.isChecked();
        // use checked here
    }
```

Also make sure you use `isChecked` to know the checked state (Do not use `isSelected()` which also exists on a Combobox)